# Is it possible to deploy one page or clsas to wildlfy?

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

my project is running in remote wildfly server, and deploy the changed by maven.

If I have just change 1 page/ or 1 class, Is it possible to deploy the singe file to remote server? by maven or by other ways?

Thanks

Comment: since my application is manged application in remote wildfly server. so I cannot deploy the page via upload file(such as ftp, ssh).

Comment: There are some who would think that doing this is not a good idea. After doing it many times you will no longer have a way of reliably reproducing the software that you have running in that environment.